# Add onEdit to existing function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty new to script but well versed with in sheet functions. I was able to coble together this function that operates like a VLOOKUP(). I don't want the VLOOKUP() because I need to be able to overwrite cells out put from the function so I turned to scripts. This script works when run but I want it to be triggered only when there is an edit to cell A2 on sheet Form. Can anybody help me add the onEdit trigger?

```
function lookUp() {
  var lookUpValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form").getRange("A2").getValue();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Current");
  var lr = ss.getLastRow()-1;
  var lookUpRangeValues = ss.getRange(2,1,lr,1).getValues();
  var newData = lookUpRangeValues.map(function(r){return r[0];});
  var index = newData.indexOf(lookUpValue)+2;
  var result = ss.getRange(index,2,1,22).getValues();
  var print = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form").getRange("B2:W2").setValues(result);

}
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");//If you not seeing this then you don't have a trigger
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  //sh.getRange('B1').setValue(JSON.stringify(e));
  //sh.getRange('C1').setValue(sh.getName());
  if (sh.getName()=='Sheet3' &&  e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart==2) {
    //e.source.toast("Past the if");
    //sh.getRange('D1').setValue(e.value);
    var lookUpValue = e.source.getSheetByName("Form").getRange("A2").getValue();
    var ss = e.source.getSheetByName("Current");
    var lr = ss.getLastRow()-1;
    var lookUpRangeValues = ss.getRange(2,1,lr,1).getValues();
    var newData = lookUpRangeValues.map(function(r){return r[0];});
    var index = newData.indexOf(lookUpValue)+2;
    var result = ss.getRange(index,2,1,22).getValues();
    sh.getRange("B2:W2").setValues(result);
  }
}
```

And I think you will need an installable onEdit trigger

[onedit  event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Note: you can't run this from the  script editor.  It must be run from an installable trigger which provide the appropriate event object.  You may use `Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e))` to learn more about the event object.

[installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Cooper, thanks but I'm unable to get the trigger to work. Also looks like you have the script set to work for the whole column A. I only need A1. Here is a copy of the sheet I'm trying to work on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ifulxw2FnW39t0vNS-UER9rPzf4RcdaGgenM-3TSJu4/edit#gid=1945340925

Comment: Sorry A2 not A1

Comment: Yeh it's setup for A2 only.  Column 1 Row 2

Comment: Did you create an installable trigger?

Comment: In the script? I read the GAS articles and it was my understanding that it needed to be written in the script? If so I tried the best I could.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot you don't go to sheets as you have helped me before. I tried both writing a trigger and using the triggers in the script editor with no success. I'm pretty sure I didn't write the trigger correctly.

Comment: Look in edit/current projects with the old editor and see if you have a trigger setup there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226115/discussion-between-badfish523-and-cooper).

Comment: Thank you @Cooper! That works great! Perfect solution!